# What is a Golden set? and what is the difference with Bagel set?

Tags: tennis, history, terminology

What is a **Golden set** on tennis?

Is there a tennis player who won a golden set?

What is the difference between **Golden set** and **Bagel set**?

Comment: Wikipedia: [Golden set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_set)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> **Golden set**: Set which is won without dropping a single point.
>
> Only one man in the history of top-tier professional tour tennis has
>   ever achieved this: **Bill Scanlon** against Marcos Hocevar in the
>   first round of the WCT Gold Coast Classic at Delray Beach on February
>   22, 1983.    Scanlon won the match 6–2, 6–0. The achievement is
>   recorded in the Guinness Book of World Records.
>
> There are only 2 women to won golden set:   In 1943, **Pauline Betz**
>   won the Tri-State tournament in Cincinnati, Ohio, defeating Catherine
>   Wolf in the final, 6–0, 6–2, without losing a point in the first set. 
>   In the 2012 Wimbledon Championships, **Yaroslava Shvedova** achieved a
>   golden set against Sara Errani. She later went on to win the match
>   6-0, 6-4.

There is also a **"Golden match"**: a match which is won without losing a single point, the entire match! but no one has won it until today..

**Bagel set** is a set which the winning player won 6-0, and the difference with **Golden set** is that you can lose points during the game as long as you win the game.

> There is a **[Golden Bagel
>   Award](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_Bagel_Award)** is an award
>   established in 2004 that honors the professional male tennis player
>   who has handed out more "bagels" (sets won 6-0), than any other player
>   on the circuit.   Roger Federer holds the all-time record for most
>   bagels in a single season with 18 going into the Tennis Master's Cup,
>   and a total of 19 in 2006.