# Won a set without dropping a point

Tags: history, trivia, tennis

Has anyone ever won a set in a grand slam without dropping a single point?

Comment: I think it could be happened many times. Be more specific.

Comment: @SportsFan you must be thinking games not points because it would be incredibly difficult to achieve. Hence why I am asking

Comment: Then you are asking about [Golden set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_set). We already had [a discussion](http://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/1056/what-is-a-golden-set-and-what-is-the-difference-with-bagel-set) about this.

Comment: @SportsFan then you should know the answer. That 'discussion' also happened to be a different question.

Comment: @user1672694 you're asking a rather...low effort question and then insulting someone asking you to clarify. That's not the kind of behavior we expect around here. Sports Fan pointed you to a question with an answer to this already, this one is getting closed.

Comment: @waxeagle I ask a legitimate question and am treated with contempt. That's not the kind of behaviour I expect around here. No-one around here knows how to give a straight answer

Comment: While it was a legitimate question, I found the answer in less than 15 seconds under the first result. Do your fair share of research *before* you ask the question, and also check other questions like @SportsFan mentioned. No need to have an attitude here.

Comment: @NicholasV. I did research but I got nothing. That's why I asked. If I had known what it was called it would have helped, but I didn't.

Comment: You have a point, results can be limited unless you have that *exact* term, then, poof: results. Just don't be insulting, eh? It's a sports QA meant to be fun, and expert driven -- not overly intense :-)

Comment: @NicholasV. there seems to be a problem with people here giving a straight 'A' from the QA. Hence my increasing frustrations

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A golden set has been seen 5 times [(1)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_set). But as to "**in a grand slam**", it looks like only one time it has happened in Grand Slam. Yaroslava Shvedova won a golden set in 2012 Wimbledon while playing against Sara Errani [(2)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_set#cite_note-3).

> The Grand Slam itinerary consists of the 1. Australian Open in mid January, the 2. French Open in May/June, 3. **Wimbledon** in June/July, and the 4. US Open in August/September.

The above quote is from [this Wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grand_Slam_%28tennis%29), and offers a lot more information on the history of Grand Slams in particular.